# BQ integration with GSC not showing all page URL's

Tags: google-bigquery, google-search-console

I need to delete a project from Big Query, as I think I set it up wrong when I was connecting GSC (it's only showing http sites not https sites), but I can't figure out how to delete it/update it to reflect https.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Check the configuration first on both GSC and BigQuery before deciding on deleting your project. Make sure you copied the specific ID of your project on your GSC settings. You can also opt to set-up your integration again to make sure if there is a bulk data exporting issue regarding the URL, which you can file on [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/). But if your project's data is still redoable, and you want fix the integration from the start, here's how to delete your project:

1. Click on the **kebab menu icon** > **Project settings** > **Shut down**
2. Follow the displayed instructions (project ID will be needed to delete project)
3. Click "Shut down" or "Delete"

You can also reverse the deletion of your project within the 30-day recovery period by [restoring the project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects?visit_id=637517042878694670-4109780680&rd=1#restoring_a_project).